# How to append a number to a RegEx region variable in PowerShell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have JPEG files in a folder named sequentially: table1.jpg, table2.jpg, table3.jpg, ..., table11.jpg

I need to do some processing on them, in sequential order, but a `Get-ChildItem` will return this (even with `Sort`):

```
table1.jpg
table10.jpg
table11.jpg
table2.jpg
table3.jpg
...
```

I would like to add a `0` to get them in the correct order:

```
table01.jpg
table02.jpg
table03.jpg
...
table11.jpg
```

I tried using RegEx with this command to preview the new names:

```
Get-ChildItem | % { $_.Name -replace "(.*[^0-9])([0-9]{1}\.jpg)",'$10$2' }
```

The idea is to get the first part of the name without any digit in first region, and one digit plus the extension in the second region. This will exclude files with two digits. And then I can replace by: first region + 0 + second region.

My problem is the "0" is seen as $10 instead of $1+"0", I don't know how to say it.

What would be the correct syntax? I tried "$10$2", "$1\0$2", "$1`0$2", '$1"0"$2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for indicating a numbered backreference without ambiguity is `${1}`.

Here's a corrected version of your statement:

```
Get-ChildItem | % { $_.Name -replace "(.*\D)(\d\.jpg)",'${1}0$2' }
```

Note: I also used `\D`, which is the built-in character class for `[^0-9]`, and `\d` in place of `[0-9]`.

Comment: This is exactly was I missed, the curly braces. Thanks for pointing out \D and \d as well. Thanks!
Answer by ojk is also very interesting. Both solve the problem.

Comment: You should upvote any answers that helped you out or provided good information. That way, you can give @ojk some credit too.

Comment: I would like and I tried but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use named groups:

```
$filename -replace "(?<first>.*[^0-9])(?<second>[0-9]{1}\.jpg)", '${first}0${second}'
```

Comment: Great! I didn't know about this. Clean and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
'"$1"0$2'
```

This should do it  .

Comment: It's closed to the solution :) It's not exactly what I look for as it puts quotes:

    "TABLE"01.jpg
    TABLE11.jpg
    TABLE12.jpg
    TABLE13.jpg
    "TABLE"02.jpg
    "TABLE"03.jpg
    "TABLE"04.jpg